# Batch file to launch XBMC URL

Tags: batch-file

I've been trying to write a simple Windows batch file to open a video file on my Media PC. When you place a URL to a media file in the quotation marks after file: and hit enter the file opens on XBMC. This is what I have so far:

```
   @echo off
   set /P url=Enter video URL: 
   start http://xbmc:8080/jsonrpc?request={"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"player.open",%%20"params":%%20{"item":{"file":""%url%""}}}
```

The webpage opens and the variable is substituted but my problem is that the quotation marks disappear. I've researched this and tried the backslash \, caret ^ and double quotes but none of these worked. A solution to this problem is greatly appreciated.
Also, I have around 10 minutes of experience with batch files so please be forgiving if the solution is simple!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way that spaces have to be replaced with %%20, quotes need to be replaced with %%22. See [this list](http://www.asciitable.com/) for other substitutions - you'll be using the value from the "hx" column.

```
@echo off
set /P url=Enter video URL: 
start http://xbmc:8080/jsonrpc?request={%%22jsonrpc%%22:%%222.0%%22,%%22method%%22:%%22player.open%%22,%%20%%22params%%22:%%20{%%22item%%22:{%%22file%%22:%%22%%22%url%%%22%%22}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your entire URL in double quotes to have the inner double quotes escaped:

```
   start "http://xbmc:8080/jsonrpc?request={"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"player.open",%%20"params":%%20{"item":{"file":""%url%""}}}"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `start` considers the first set of quotes it encounters to be the window title, so the command in this case should start as `start "" "http...`